# How to add a secondary parent to an Alfresco folder

Tags: alfresco

In Alfresco, a single document can have several parent folders. Example: myfolder can be found both in folder1 and folder2.

**QUESTION**: How to easily create such a situation?

I want to create this kind of structure in order to perform tests.

Answer (score 0):

This method requires admin access, server access, and it is not user-friendly, but it is still the easiest method I know about.

1. Install Maven
2. Download the source code of https://github.com/share-extras/js-console
3. At the root level of this source code, run `mvn package`
4. From the same folder, copy the created packages to Alfresco (replace $YOUR_ALFRESCO with the path to your Alfresco server):

Commands:

```
cp ./javascript-console-repo/target/*.amp $YOUR_ALFRESCO/amps/
cp ./javascript-console-share/target/*.amp $YOUR_ALFRESCO/amps_share/
```

5. Go to the folder of your Alfresco server, stop Alfresco, then run `bin/apply_amps.sh`
6. Start Alfresco again, open Alfresco Share in a browser, click on `Admin Tools` then `JavaScript Console` (if it does not appear, there was a problem with the previous steps)
7. Paste this code, replace the IDs with the IDs of existing folders on your Alfresco server, and execute:

Code:

```
var parent = search.findNode("node", ["workspace", "SpacesStore",
                               "65ba5b62-a7ae-4759-9a26-9abcf852cbb2"]);
var child = search.findNode("node", ["workspace", "SpacesStore",
                               "e1f0ce82-f4f0-4cfc-9bce-ded174abeddf"]);
parent.addNode(child);
```